# Call TFS rest API

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to call Windows TFS rest API to get git repo information.

I can call the Windows TFS rest API to list the git repos using postman.

ie. get tfs git repos:

GET  http://tfs_url:8080/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/repo-name?api-version=1.0

However, I am having issues calling it using `HttpClient 4.5.x`

By using Fiddler, I can see postman is using NTLM even though i did not add any Authorization headers.

The Java Client code:

```
private void getRequest() throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new NTCredentials("user", "password", "workstation", "domain"));

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("tfs.web.com", 8080, "http");

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/repo-name");
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, context);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        response1.close();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The target server failed to respond

The same code works on a colleague's machine, so there MUST be something that is blocking the call on my machine, and ideas?

Please advise.

Comment: The issue seems like a proxy issue. If I proxy using fiddler or tunnelij, the request gets redirected correctly and works. So how can I address the proxy issue?

Comment: DNS settings were corrupted on machine. I had to ipconfig flushdns and ipconfig registerdns. This may have happened because I installed virtualbox and openshift stuff. After this the web service started working.